# Inkscape: Path Division removes image

Tags: inkscape

I have two paths - one traced bitmap, another created from rectangle. I want to separate lower part of the traced image by using the rectangle path. However Path Division removes the whole image. Could you please advise what is wrong?
[Link to SVG.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4r06lecw1sgo5sr/Division.svg/file)

Comment: Could you open a bug report about this at https://inkscape.org/report , please?

Comment: Submitted https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a Division operation for this. It seems to be too complex for Inkscape to calculate. There may be a limit on the number of paths which Division will work with. Do this instead:

1. Select the graphic and do *Path > Break apart*.
2. Select all the pieces of the top part only, and do *Path > Combine*.
3. Repeat step 2 for the lower part.

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution works!

Comment: Another option: Duplicate, and do Path > Difference twice, with a rectangle covering one, and then the other part.

Comment: @Moini - yes that works too.  Do you think the problem with Division is a bug, or is it because of the complexity of the combined paths? I notice the same problem in both 0.92 and 1.0 for what it's worth.

Comment: I think it's a bug, but I didn't examine the path too closely.